# Online Classical Chinese dictionary

Tags: resources

There are two similar questions here:
[what are some dictionaries about vocabulary of classical chinese?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9888/what-are-some-dictionaries-about-vocabulary-of-classical-chinese)
[Resources: Modern Chinese -> Classical Chinese (Dictionary/References/etc.)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/12685/resources-modern-chinese-classical-chinese-dictionary-references-etc)

But my question is different: I am looking for an online Classical Chinese dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much, I suppose.

If you have access to Brill, then the [Chinese-English Dictionary Online](https://chinesereferenceshelf.brillonline.com/chinese-english) contains the entries, among others, from Paul W. Kroll's [A Student's Dictionary of Classical and Medieval Chinese](https://brill.com/view/title/20918). But randomly having access to Brill is one of the most rare things in the world though ($160 and that expires after five years of usage???)

Alternatively, if you have Pleco, you may purchase the same Kroll as a $40 add-on and browse it with ease in a native iOS or Android app. They also have the 漢語大詞典 for $50, which covers all the periods of the language including Classical, and the Gu Hanyu Da Cidian for $20, specifically aimed at Classical language.

If you are looking for a free source, consider [the dictionary of ctext.org](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en). If not much, it will at least provide the whole text of Kangxi dictionary definition in a digitized format, so if you already read Classical Chinese on a basic level, it will allow to get the general gist of things.

Personally, out of the non-Chinese language dictionaries of Classical Chinese, I am very partial to the dictionary attached to Kai Vogelsang's [Introduction to Classical Chinese](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/introduction-to-classical-chinese-9780198834977?cc=ru&lang=en&), so if there is any chance to (somehow, such as through institutional access) get hold of it, it would be probably a better option than all of the entries above. I mean, it contains the data that one generally expects from a language dictionary (such as Old Chinese pronuunciation, parts of speech, how the word combines with other words), which Classical Chinese dictionaries ordinarily neglect. Kroll is a helpful addition to that, but only an addition; its definitions are brief, and its stronger sides are just more characters and medieval usages.

Out of the Chinese-language dictionaries of Classical Chinese, then probably the 古漢語字典 by Wang Li would be the best option.

Comment: Thank you. There is also this online dictionary: https://www.zdic.net/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest dict.cn.com. It is an online, English-Chinese and Chinese-English, two-way dictionary.

[image]